# Just got my 1st laptop and the touch pad is being uncooperative

Tags: touchpad, acer-aspire

I purchased a new Acer laptop about a week ago. Everything on it works just fine with the exception that the touch pad acts strange at times. Sometimes, it clicks a check box when I scroll over it even though I didn't click the left button. I went to the Programs and Features option in Control Panel and it almost deleted something I didn't want to because it clicked it as I scrolled over. Any way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you tap lightly on your touch pad, the touch pad sees that as a left click. This is something that you can disable easily.

Try going into the Control panel and double click the Mouse icon to open it. 
In there should be a tab for your synaptics mouse pad.
You should be able to change all the tap functions there.

[image]

[source](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/181954-how-do-you-disable-touchpad-tap-to-click/)

Comment: Thanks for the clear, concise answer. Have no problems now with this.

Comment: your welcome ;D happy i could help